# Is "break" necessary here for stopping the loop

Tags: javascript, break

Is "break" necessary here for stopping the loop? The output is not changing with or without it.

```
var cleanCities = ["Argentina" , "Brazil", "Canada", "Denmark"];
var visit = prompt("What is your city?");
var numLength = cleanCities.length;
var matchFound = false;

for (i=0; i<numLength ; i++) 
    if (visit === cleanCities[i]) {
        matchFound = true;
        alert ("It is really a nice City" + i)
        break;
    }

if (matchFound === false){
    alert ("It is not in the List");
}
```

Comment: Let's imagine you are living in a 5 bedrooms house and have lost one sock. You know you've lost it in one of the bedrooms. You started visiting every room and found it in the 2nd one. Will you go to the remaining 3 rooms?

Comment: love the analogy (maybe change 'left' to 'remaining')...? ;)

Comment: You keep posting this code that is broken and that last if is still in the wrong place. AND modern browsers have indexOf.

Comment: Btw, these are countries, not cities. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not necessary as such, but what happens if you have a duplicate i.e. "Argentina" twice in your cleanCities list.

It's better to be extra safe and ensure the program will work correctly even with unexpected data.

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 reason to include the `break`:

1. If `cleanCities` contains a matching value twice in the list, the user would get 2 "It is a really a nice City" alerts.
2. If your array contains a lot of items, the `break` would be more efficient because the code could stop looking for another value.

Comment: I would argue that break is *necessary* to clearly convey the intent - not just for "efficiency" reasons. Without it, the intent might be to find the last match (or alert many times or count the number of matches or ..)

Answer (score 0):

The result may be the same in this case, but it's good practice to shortcut things once you have what you need.  Using break is the way to go.

Comment: "The result will be the same" --- because of `alert` - nope

Answer (score 0):

In the current scenario, `break` is not necessary, 
but it certainly will optimize the performance of your code. Using `break`, It will not check for other cities as soon as it has found a match.

Answer (score 0):

Is is good to have break. If Argentina is entered the for loop will only iterate once and quit. If the list was long say 500 item you would notice a big difference in the execution time when break is removed.

Answer (score 0):

Basically it "breaks" (stops) the loop the *first* time the statement in which it is becomes true.

> Terminates the current loop, switch, or label statement and transfers program control to the statement following the terminated statement.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break

In your example it doesn't change a thing because you only have one occurrence of each country (not city ;), therefore `value` will always only match one of them in the `cleanCities` array. If you had multiple cities (countries) with the same name, break would catch the first one and stop the loop.